# Authenticating and ASP.NET Core application with ADFS and SAML

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, adfs

I've searched over Internet and I couldn't find any good resources explaining how to authenticate an ASP.NET Core web application through ADFS using the SAML protocol.

However, I found an old blog post saying that it was not supported and that it would not be until at least .NET Core 2.1. Except of that, I didn't find anything else.

However, I can't believe that something so important is not yet supported...

Does anyone has any experience with that? Note that Azure is not an option here.

Comment: IdentityServer4 supports them.

Comment: I checked a bit because I didn't know this. Am I right if I say that IS4 is a NuGet package that I can install and that understand the SAML returned by ADFS ?

Comment: IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core 2. I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZzFPhVkzo4&t=2012s) on youtube and it shows that it supports ADFS and SAML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - see this example using [Sustainsys](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-adfs-5-0-and-the-sustainsys-saml-v2-0-for-net-core-stack-1c8dd8f4aecd).

You can also use ComponentSpace (examples in that blog) or Rock Solid Knowledge as per this [example](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-adfs-and-the-identityserver-4-saml2p-identity-provider-e0593c54746e).